# location.hash for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, hash, smarty

So i'm adding a "#something" at the end of the address bar and depending on "something" some particular elements have to be shown
for example

```
if(location.hash == '#coffee'){
        $('#mcoffee').show();
        $('#rmcoffee').show();
```

but i've noticed that the hash is not added to the address on the mobile devices (on all desktop browsers it works fine).
The code for adding hash:

```
<span class="left-2" onclick="window.location = '{$BASE_URL}/kawamenu.html#{$v.name}'">
```

note: i'm using smarty to get the category name

Am I missing something specific that should be added to code to make it work on mobile devices ?
Any help would be appreciated.

**upd**

working example can be found [here](http://www.kawymagia.lviv.ua/)

Comment: Do you mean mobile Browsers by *mobile devices* or do you mean something like Cordova?

Comment: @Nano mobile Browsers by mobile devices

Comment: `location.hash` shoud work on all major Browsers.

Comment: @Nano when i click on span in desktop browser i get the following address:   http://www.kawymagia.lviv.ua/kawamenu.html?page=16#coffee   
but when i click on it in mobile browser i get the following:   
http://www.kawymagia.lviv.ua/kawamenu.html?page=16

Comment: then there is something wrong with your `$v.name` variable, if the hash isnt set

Comment: @Nano those are just string variables, nothing special

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve it @user3670146? Anyone have any ideas?